# How do I add and remove class in between this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this scripts that either enable or disable an submit button. My issue here is I want to remove the current class (yellow) and add a new one (green) if the inputs aren't empty. Also the value of the button I want to change from "Order Now!" to "Proceed!". I've tried checking the fields with an if-statement, but it didn't work out, the only part I can get to work is wether or not the submit is disabled.

My submit button are like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit-order-btn yellow" value="Order now!">
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
var $submit = $('.submit-order-btn'),
    $inputs = $('input[type=text]');

function checkEmpty() {
    return $inputs.filter(function() {
        return !$.trim(this.value);
    }).length === 0;
}

$inputs.on('blur keyup', function() {
    $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
}).blur();

// DEBUG BEGIN \\
$submit.on("click", function() {
        alert("Submitted");
});
// DEBUG END \\
```

Comment: Does the `checkEmpty()` function work? Or do you need help figuring that out as well?

Comment: It works fine :) thought I can't figure out how to add/remove CSS classes in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on when you want the class and value change to happen, do you mean like this?

```
$inputs.on('blur keyup', function() {
    $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());

    if (!checkEmpty()) {
        $submit.removeClass('yellow').addClass('green');
        $submit.val('Proceed!');
    } else {
        $submit.removeClass('green').addClass('yellow');
        $submit.val('Order now!');
    }
}).blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this just with css:

```
.yellow{
    background-color:green;
}
input[type="submit"]:disabled{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/FR75Q/

Comment: glad i could be of help. please dont forget to mark the answer to your question so others can find it if needed :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like `.addClass('')` and `.removeClass('')`?
Sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/AJLsz/

Comment: Yes, exactly though I tried with both, and I couldn't get it to work. I'm using your solution, thanks man.